# How many hydrogen environments are there in phenyl acetic acid?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, hydrogen

How does the molecule below have only three hydrogen environments? Should it not have 5 different hydrogen environments according to the labelled diagram?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also: [Phenyl group in proton NMR](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32661).

Comment: You are correct that there are 5 different hydrogen environments in phenylacetic acid. But whether or not the aromatic hydrogens are resolvable at some particular magnetic field is a different issue. The lower the field; the lower the chances.